# How to sell a product upgrade?

Tags: pricebook

We have several products that we sell (Say P, G, D)

While for new customers it's easy, I am confused on how to sell an upgrade of any product.

example: in 2015, our **P** product will get a new version: **V2**

How would I set that in SF?

New Product? That's misleading - we only sell one.

How will I setup a version upgrade ? customer purchased the upgrade from V1 to V2 at 15% of MSRP ?

We don't use assets nor subscriptions, nor entitlements.

Answer (score 1):

In orgs I have been associated with, separate SKUs are used for the base product and the upgrade product - that is, two separate Product2 records.

If the Base Product is priced at $10.00, then the PricebookEntry for the upgrade Product is $1.50

It gets more interesting when the upgrade product is sold as a % of whatever the customer actually paid for the base product (that is, after discounts). I would still tend to have a PricebookEntry for the upgrade product at list prices (i.e. $1.50) but use a custom quoting VF page that would calculate the offered upgrade price based on prior purchase history for that customer (that is, look at prior closed won Opportunity Products to generate past purchase history - or maybe the new Orders standard object).